# How to parse XML (especific structure) in Android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I need to parse a specific part of an XML obtained from a http request but I do not know how to do it!

I have the following XML structure being returned:

```
<categorias type="array">
    <categoria>
        <nome>
        Alimentação
        </nome>
        <idcategoria>
        5
        </idcategoria>
        <subcategorias>
            <subcategoria>
                <nome>
                Todos
                </nome>
                <id>
                5
                </id>
            </subcategoria>
        </subcategorias>
    </categoria>
</categorias>
```

I need to parse the data inside the subcategorias 
tag because with the code I have now, I get only the upper tags, like 
nome and idcategoria from the root tag categoria.

I've created a NodeList inside the for loop but it return all the subcategoria tags in the Document. And I need to get only the ones inside a unique categoria tag.
Here's the code I have now:

```
menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }
```

Can someone help me on this!?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I need to parse the data inside the tag" - What data inside of what tag?

Comment: Side note: your comments are a little unnecessary, don't you think? :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [official document of Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) which describe **XMLPullParser**.

You have to implement your logic according to your XML structure.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from XMLPullParser, another option for parsing XML is to use the [Simple XML library](http://simple.sourceforge.net/). It will allow you to easily deserialize that XML into an object which you can manipulate however you wish. It would be possible for you to ignore all other child elements in categoria and just capture subcategorias by using loose object mapping. Check the Simple Framework documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

@Android Coader is right, "You have to implement your logic according to your XML structure"

Why do you have a KEY_ITEM, when there are no "item" tags in your XML? You need to specify in the code which tags you want to retrieve. For example, if you define a KEY_SUBCATEGORIA = "subcategoria", then to get all subcategory nodes you can do

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SUBCATEGORIA);
```

Then you should navigate through each node, pulling out the name and id's as you are doing now.

Comment: The term KEY_ITEM can be replaced by KEY_CATEGORIA.
My problem in the moment is how to navigate through the <subcategoria> tags!

Do I need to create another NodeList inside the for loop I have now?
Because I can have many results with the tag <subcategoria>

Comment: If you just want to get *every single* subcategoria tag in the document, then what you have now is fine.

Comment: Creating another NodeList and getting the elements with tag <subcategoria> it returns all the tags in the document but I need to get the tag <subcategoria> that are inside each tag <categoria>.

Comment: You should really clarify your question then, this should have been stated from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!
I used only the same kind of structure I had before!

I added this code inside the for loop I had:

```
NodeList nlSubcategorias = e.getElementsByTagName("subcategoria");
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> subcategorias = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        for (int j = 0; j < nlSubcategorias.getLength(); j++) {
            HashMap<String, String> mapSub = new HashMap<String, String>();

            Element eSub = (Element)nlSubcategorias.item(j);

            mapSub.put(KEY_ID_SUB, parser.getValue(eSub, KEY_ID_SUB));
            mapSub.put(KEY_NAME_SUB, parser.getValue(eSub, KEY_NAME_SUB));

            subcategorias.add(mapSub);

            System.out.println("subcategorias: " + subcategorias.get(j).get(KEY_NAME_SUB));
        }
        subcategoriasItems.add(subcategorias);
```